# Forward all TCP and UDP connections over VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, udp

I have the following setup:

OS: Ubuntu v13
Software: PPTP

**NIC 1** (eth1)
IP: 10.2.95.207/24
Gateway: 10.2.95.1
(this is the network I want to connect to)

**NIC 2** (eth2)
IP: 7.82.176.254/8
(the network I want to connect from)

**PPTP** is set to
local IP: 10.2.95.208
remote IP range: 10.2.95.212 to 219

**sysctl.conf**
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

**rc.local**
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

What I want to achieve

1. Connect using PPTP from Windows 8.1 and take IP 10.0.0.0/24 (DONE!)
2. Access computers that are base 10.0.0.0/8 (DONE!)
3. Forward all UDP traffic to the network I am connecting from (I don't know how to do it)

There is a game server on that network that I want to access. When I scan for it from the game lobby in the same network, I can see it, but when I scan from behind the VPN, I can't see it, although I can ping the IP and access the computer itself (remote desktop).

I guessed that the problem is with UDP forwarding.